# Laravel 5.1 installation error (php artisan clear-compiled)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I run laravel new auth and get the following error. I'm using Windows 7 if that helps.

```
C:\wamp\www>laravel new auth
Crafting application...
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> php artisan clear-compiled

Fatal error: Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_inter
nal_encoding() in C:\wamp\www\auth\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php on line 2117
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\mb_
internal_encoding() in C:\wamp\www\auth\bootstrap\cache\compiled.php on line 211
7
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned w
ith an error



  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Illuminate\Found
  ation\Bootstrap\mb_internal_encoding() in C:\wamp\www\auth\bootstrap\cache\
  compiled.php on line 2117
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment the following lines in php.ini

```
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

And restart apache.

Mbstring is necessary to make a strong hash.

Answer (score 0):

remove all the files from C:\wamp\www\auth\bootstrap\cache\ this directory,then run

```
composer install
```

from terminal